# Change resource properties to plain text

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I want to change all appearance Properties.Resources.XXX in project to text value which is in *.resx file

eg

```
var someText= Properties.Resources.someText;
//I want to change to
var someText= "some text";
```

I'm searching solution in ResXManager but i did not found

Comment: `<CTRL> + H`, Find & Replace. Unless you mean at run-time. If so, you could set `var someText= $"{Some Field}";`

Comment: yes it is a good idea, but I have thousands different values to replace, so i'm searching some kind of tool for that